# Site-to-Site VPN Tunnel Up Not Passing Traffic

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa

I have a site-to-site VPN that seems to be dropping traffic from a particular subnet when a lot of data is being pushed through the tunnel. I have to run `clear ipsec sa` to get it going again.

I notice the following when running `show crypto ipsec sa`. The SA timing remaining key lifetime reaches 0 for kB. When this happens the tunnel doesn't pass traffic. I don't understand why it doesn't rekey.

```
inbound esp sas:
      spi: 0x51BB8CAE (1371245742)
         transform: esp-3des esp-sha-hmac no compression
         in use settings ={L2L, Tunnel, }
         slot: 0, conn_id: 65753088, crypto-map: OutsideCrypto_map
         sa timing: remaining key lifetime (kB/sec): (3796789/14690)
         IV size: 8 bytes
         replay detection support: Y
         Anti replay bitmap:
          0xFFFFFFFF 0xFFFFFFFF
    outbound esp sas:
      spi: 0x91CA1D71 (2445942129)
         transform: esp-3des esp-sha-hmac no compression
         in use settings ={L2L, Tunnel, }
         slot: 0, conn_id: 65753088, crypto-map: OutsideCrypto_map
         **sa timing: remaining key lifetime (kB/sec): (0/14678)**
         IV size: 8 bytes
         replay detection support: Y
         Anti replay bitmap:
          0x00000000 0x00000001
```

### UPDATE 7/1/2013

I am running ASA 8.6.1. Researching Cisco's site I was able to find [Bug CSCtq57752](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/BugToolKit/search/getBugDetails.do?method=fetchBugDetails&bugId=CSCtq57752&Submit=Search). The details are

> ASA: IPSec outbound SA data lifetime rekey fails Symptom:
>
> IPSec outbound SA fails to rekey when data lifetime reaches zero kB.
>
> Conditions:
>
> ASA has an IPSec tunnel with a remote peer. The data lifetime on the
>   ASA reaches 0 kB, the lifetime in seconds has not yet expired.
>
> Workaround:
>
> Increase the data lifetime to a very high value (or even the maximum
>   value), or decrease the lifetime in seconds. The lifetime in seconds
>   should ideally expire before the data limit in kB reaches zero. In
>   this manner the rekey will be triggered based on seconds, and the data
>   lifetime issue can be bypassed.

The solution is to update to version 8.6.1(5). I'm going to try and schedule a maintenance window tonight and see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: What are the lifetime settings on both sides?

Comment: It's 8 hours and/or 4608000 KBytes. When the KBytes hit 0 it doesn't renegotiate the tunnel.

Comment: @Rowell, regarding your 7/1/2013 update.. if a SW upgrade resolves your problem, please post it as an answer instead of an edit to your question...

Comment: @MikePennington I definitely intend on posting it as a solution if it is resolved. I will cross my fingers.

Comment: @rowell if you write a separate answer -- it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question -- I can aware you the +50 bounty (if you write the answer quickly before the bounty expires tomorrow(wed jul 10). )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The resolution to my problem is to upgrade my ASA image to 8.6.1(5).

This resolves bug [CSCtq57752](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/BugToolKit/search/getBugDetails.do?method=fetchBugDetails&bugId=CSCtq57752&Submit=Search)

The workaround to the bug is to lower the crypto map's timed lifetime and increase the crypto map's traffic volume threshold:

```
crypto map *YOUR-CRYPTO-MAP ID* set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
crypto map *YOUR-CRYPTO-MAP ID* set security-association lifetime kilobytes 2147483647
```

The above crypto map lowers the lifetime to 3600 seconds and increases the kilobytes threshold to the highest value. In my case, I just have to ensure the seconds lifetime is depleted before the kilobytes threshold.